# A free hosting for a single static HTML file that is uploaded with API?

Tags: web-hosting

Any suggestions how can I host a small HTML file like 20-30kb for free?
It doesn't intend to live long, could be deleted after a while.

I should be able to POST the HTML content with `fetch()`...